# On Android, Where else can a FlutterEngine be displayed except for Activity (and when?)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

**In what other cases is the `FlutterEngine` available but the Android Activity isn't?** For example, if I am running a static BroadcastReceiver when the app is not running, there is definitely no activity, but is there a `FlutterEngine`? I need to know the characteristics of Flutter in the Android lifecycle. I was reading an article ([Modern Flutter Plugin Development](https://medium.com/flutter/modern-flutter-plugin-development-4c3ee015cf5a)) by the Flutter team, which mentions

> ```
> // You cannot access an Activity here because this 
> // FlutterEngine is not necessarily displayed within an 
> // Activity. See the ActivityAware interface for more info.
> ```

---

This is partially answered in the `ActivityAware` [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/plugins/activity/ActivityAware.html), under the `onDetachedFromActivity` method.

> Detachment can occur for a number of reasons.
>
> - The app is no longer visible and the Activity instance has been destroyed.
> - The FlutterEngine that this plugin is connected to has been detached from its FlutterView.
> - This ActivityAware plugin has been removed from its FlutterEngine.

However, I wish it went into more depth. Here are some things I (don't) understand in depth:

- When the activity is destroyed as per the Android activity lifecycle, the activity is gone. The FlutterEngine might still be around, in case a new activity is launched in the future. Perhaps there is still a component running in the Android app, e.g. a Service, and the FlutterEngine does not get destroyed yet? **I wonder which cases FlutterEngine does not get destroyed when the activity gets destroyed.**
- A FlutterView can [detach from the engine](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterView.html#detachFromFlutterEngine--), and this is probably done if you're adding/ removing Flutter from a native Android app (aka. using [add-to-app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app)). You probably don't have to worry about `FlutterView` detaching from `FlutterEngine`. **In a normal Flutter app, in what cases does `FlutterView` detach from `FlutterEngine`**?:

  > This FlutterView will clear its UI and stop forwarding all events to the previously-attached FlutterEngine. This includes touch events, accessibility events, keyboard events, and others.
- The relatively easy one: If a plugin unregisters from the FlutterEngine, Flutter cleans up the plugin by calling this method. You don't manually unregister plugins. You'd have to find out when Flutter unregisters plugins on your behalf. **When?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To answer my questions after reading the Flutter Android shell code:*

### **I wonder which cases FlutterEngine does not get destroyed when the activity gets destroyed.**

When a Fragment or Activity gets detached or destroyed, the Engine **might** get destroyed. This is the only case where this happens. The Activity/ Fragment being destroyed is configurable by e.g. `EXTRA_DESTROY_ENGINE_WITH_ACTIVITY`:

```
  @Override
  public boolean shouldDestroyEngineWithHost() {
    boolean explicitDestructionRequested =
        getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_DESTROY_ENGINE_WITH_ACTIVITY, false);
    if (getCachedEngineId() != null || delegate.isFlutterEngineFromHost()) {
      // Only destroy a cached engine if explicitly requested by app developer.
      return explicitDestructionRequested;
    } else {
      // If this Activity created the FlutterEngine, destroy it by default unless
      // explicitly requested not to.
      return getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_DESTROY_ENGINE_WITH_ACTIVITY, true);
    }
  }
```

*or for fragments:*

```
  @Override
  public boolean shouldDestroyEngineWithHost() {
    boolean explicitDestructionRequested =
        getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_DESTROY_ENGINE_WITH_FRAGMENT, false);
    if (getCachedEngineId() != null || delegate.isFlutterEngineFromHost()) {
      // Only destroy a cached engine if explicitly requested by app developer.
      return explicitDestructionRequested;
    } else {
      // If this Fragment created the FlutterEngine, destroy it by default unless
      // explicitly requested not to.
      return getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_DESTROY_ENGINE_WITH_FRAGMENT, true);
    }
  }
```

*Therefore, the user can actually specify this.*

- If the flutter engine is cached, it won't get destroyed. It doesn't get put into the cache by default, developers have to do this themselves. Therefore, not relevant in a normal flutter app.
- If the activity/ fragment creates this FlutterEngine, it gets destroyed. This is the default case in a normal Flutter app.
- Both of the above can be disabled by the user if they explicitly set it.

The mechanism to **destroy a FlutterEngine**, aka. when `flutterEngine.destroy();` is called, is done only in `onDetach()` of the FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate. So the question would be: **when does the Activity get detached?**

### **In a normal Flutter app, in what cases does FlutterView detach from FlutterEngine?:**

- When the FlutterView is attempting to attach to a different Flutter engine, it will detach from its current FlutterEngine, if it is attached.
- The FlutterView will detach from the Engine when the Activity or Fragment is being detached from the Flutter Engine. Right before the FlutterEngine might get destroyed.

### You'd have to find out when Flutter unregisters plugins on your behalf. When?

When the Activity or Fragment detaches from the `FlutterEngine`, and the FlutterEngine is destroyed, its associated PluginRegistry is destroyed, and when this happens, all the plugins are removed by calling `PluginRegistry.removeAll`.`

Answer (score 0):

`I wonder which cases FlutterEngine does not get destroyed when the activity gets destroyed.`

I think it depends on which activity and how you've decided to implement it.

I imagine one scenario is, an instance of **FlutterEngine** is created by the **MainActivity** and lives for as long as that activity is around.

If you have more than one **Activity** then you'd have a choice. Keep a single **FlutterEngine** instance around in memory and attach/detach the various activities, or destroy the instance and create a new for for each Activity.

I couldn't comment on best practice.

**Running multiple Flutters**

Though this link raises an interesting scenario.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/multiple-flutters

**FlutterView**

Not entirely sure what your question is here. But given https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-view It appears that you do a lot of manual binding between the activity, view and your Flutter view (binding thats done automatically with the FlutterFragment or FlutterActivity)

As such, when the FlutterView is or is not disaplayed is very much tied to the activity Life cycle in control of that View and the bindings you setup in the first instance.

The link above also states the minimum API's to implement for FlutterView to work properly.

```
The absolute minimum implementation needed for Flutter to draw anything at all is to:

Call attachToFlutterEngine when the FlutterView is added to a resumed
Activity’s view hierarchy and is visible; and
Call appIsResumed on the FlutterEngine’s lifecycleChannel field when
the Activity hosting the FlutterView is visible.

The reverse detachFromFlutterEngine and other lifecycle methods on the
LifecycleChannel class must also be called to not leak resources when
the FlutterView or Activity is no longer visible.
```

Comment: My question isn't related to Add to app, I just want to understand in which cases a FlutterEngine exists when the activity does not. I've bolded my 3 primary questions now (there are 3 documented ways an activity will detach from the FlutterEngine), but I don't think you answer any of them currently.

Comment: FlutterEngine is created i believe when you setup Flutter to exist in an app. I.e. the MainActivity will create an instance. How long that instance lasts depends on if the MainActivity keeps it alive in memory, or bins it when the MainActivity closes. 

So Its existence depends on how you start it off initially. I.e. saving the instance to a static prop or in a local var.